# Show that, in general, if D is a domain, and d∈D is a g.c.d. of a and b, then all the g.c.d.’s of a and b are precisely the associates of d.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory

[image]

Can y'all check my proof?  I'm kinda tripping over "unit".  Did I prove associates or do I have to show that $u$ is a unit?

[here is the definition they mention from the previous problem]

[image]

Comment: In a domain it may not be possible to divide by $r$, so the expression $\frac{r_0}{r}g$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: That's only if r=0 which makes no sense since a=rd and d|a.  how could r possibility be 0?  But I could explicitly state that r isn't 0.

Comment: No; for example $\Bbb{Z}[X]$ is a domain, but $X$ has no inverse.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm REALLY struggling in this class, and that means nothing to me.  :(   (gonna go find a video on domains)   (again)

Comment: Alternatively; in the integers the number $2$ has no inverse. That is, there is no integer $n$ such that $2n=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a domain it may not be possible to divide by $r$, so the expression $\frac{r_0}{r}g$ doesn't make sense.

For the proof you really need property ${\rm ii)}$ of your definition:

If $d_1$ and $d_2$ are gcd's of $a$ and $b$ then $d_1\mid d_2$ and $d_2\mid d_1$, meaning that there exist $r_1,r_2\in D$ such that $d_1=r_1d_2$ and $d_2=r_2d_1$. Then $d_1=r_1r_2d_1$, which we can rearrange to
$$d_1(1-r_1r_2)=0.$$
Because $D$ is a domain this implies that either $d_1=0$ or $1-r_1r_2=0$, or both. So if $d_1\neq0$ then $r_1r_2=1$, which means precisely that $r_1$ is a unit. And from $d_1=r_1d_2$ we now see that $d_1$ and $d_2$ are associate.

The case $d_1=0$ I leave to you.

Comment: I don't understand why it may not be possible to divide by r.  We are talking about integers, so as long as it's stated that r isn't 0, why can't I divide by r?

Comment: Your question (as I read it) is about a domain $D$, not necessarily the integers. As for the integers; it is true that
$$5\times6=3\times10\qquad\text{ so }\qquad 6=\frac{3}{5}\times10,$$
but $\frac{3}{5}$ is not an integer and certainly not a unit in the integers.

Comment: Ok, that I understand.

Comment: if d=0, then d can't divide g (or a or b for that matter), so d CANNOT be zero.  Yes?

Comment: Almost; if $d=0$ then $0\mid a$ and $0\mid b$, meaning that $a=b=0$. In this case $0$ is the unique gcd of $a$ and $b$, but this is more of a formality than anything else.